# What is the best way to read input of unpredictable and indeterminate (ie no EOF) size from stdin in C?

Tags: c

This ***must*** be a stupid question because this should be a very common and simple problem, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere, so I'll bite the bullet and ask.

How on earth should I go about reading from the standard input when there is no way of determining the size of the data? Obviously if the data ends in some kind of terminator like a NUL or EOF then this is quite trivial, but my data does not. This is simple IPC: the two programs need to talk back and forth and ending the file streams with EOF would break everything.

I thought this should be fairly simple. Clearly programs talk to each other over pipes all the time without needing any arcane tricks, so I hope there is a simple answer that I'm too stupid to have thought of. Nothing I've tried has worked.

Something obvious like (ignoring necessary realloc's for brevity):

```
int size = 0, max = 8192;
unsigned char *buf = malloc(max);
while (fread((buf + size), 1, 1, stdin) == 1)
    ++size;
```

won't work since fread() blocks and waits for data, so this loop won't terminate. As far as I know nothing in stdio allows nonblocking input, so I didn't even try any such function. Something like this is the best I could come up with:

```
struct mydata {
    unsigned char *data;
    int slen; /* size of data */
    int mlen; /* maximum allocated size */
};

...

struct mydata *buf = xmalloc(sizeof *buf);
buf->data = xmalloc((buf->mlen = 8192));
buf->slen = 0;

int nread = read(0, buf->data, 1);
if (nread == (-1))
        err(1, "read error");

buf->slen += nread;
fcntl(0, F_SETFL, oflags | O_NONBLOCK);

do {
    if (buf->slen >= (buf->mlen - 32))
        buf->data = xrealloc(buf->data, (buf->mlen *= 2));
    nread = read(0, (buf->data + buf->slen), 1);
    if (nread > 0)
        buf->slen += nread;
} while (nread == 1);

fcntl(0, F_SETFL, oflags);
```

where `oflags` is a global variable containing the original flags for stdin (cached at the start of the program, just in case). This dumb way of doing it works as long as all of the data is present immediately, but fails otherwise. Because this sets read() to be non-blocking, it just returns -1 if there is no data. The program communicating with mine generally sends responses whenever it feels like it, and not all at once, so if the data is at all large this exits too early and fails.

Comment: *How on earth should I go about reading from the standard input when there is no way of determining the size of the data?* You read and process data in small manageable pieces, and discard processed pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How on earth should I go about reading from the standard input when there is no way of determining the size of the data?

There always has to be a way to determinate the size. Otherwise, the program would require infinite memory, and thus impossible to run on a physical computer.

Think about it this way: even in the case of a never-ending stream of data, there must be some chunks or points where you have to process it. For instance, a live-streamed video has to decode a portion of it (e.g. a frame). Or a video game which processes messages one by one, even if the game has undetermined length.

This holds true regardless of the type of I/O you decide to use (blocking/non-blocking, synchronous/asynchronous...). For instance, if you want to use typical blocking synchronous I/O, what you have to do is process the data in a loop: each iteration, you read as much data as is available, and process as much as you can. Whatever you can not process (because you have not received enough yet), you keep for the next iteration. Then, the rest of the loop is the rest of the logic of the program.

In the end, regardless of what you do, you (or someone else, e.g. a library, the operating system, the hardware buffers...) have to buffer incoming data until it can be processed.

Comment: Have you tried to read everything from `/dev/urandom`? (or work out its size)

Comment: @EdHeal: It seems to me you haven't understood the answer.

Comment: _There always has to be a way to determinate the size_ - How do you do this for `/dev/urandom` (BTW you can pipe that file into stdin in a progran

Comment: @EdHeal: The size of the data that you have to work with **at a single point in time**. The answer is actually explaining the point that you have missed: that you cannot hold infinite data in memory, and therefore any valid program has to process some chunk of an infinite input stream (like `/dev/urandom`).

Comment: I was perhaps overstating the situation a little bit. I was hoping that there was some way to read data without knowing the size. This particular data does have the size encoded into it, but not anywhere easy to read. To know the size of the data I would have to process and decode the data byte by byte as I read it. It was much easier to decode when I had all of it already (and even then I've never done more bit twiddling and nonsense in my life). Back to the drawing board I suppose.

Comment: @Roflcopter4: Well, you can always read as much as you can fit in memory -- if that is enough to simplify your design, by all means, go for it! But indeed, it looks like your problem is about receiving an stream of data, and that requires processing it on the fly as you go. If you have never done it, it indeed requires a new perspective on how to handle such problems. But knowing how to do it is very useful, even in problems where you *do* know the size and can hold it in memory!

Comment: @Acorn Well, ultimately I got it working, though it took rewriting half the decoding code. And I suppose chopping the memory using by more than half isn't anything to sneeze at either. Now I just need to deal with the fact that somehow my data structures are so inefficient that the program allocates 200Kb of memory to decode the value "[0, 0, NIL, 1]", but that's another question entirely...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have two choices -- synchronous or asynchronous -- and both have their advantages and disadvantages.

For synchronous, you need either delimeters or a length field embedded in the record (or fixed length records, but that is pretty inflexible).  This works best for synchronous protocols like synchronous rpc or simplex client-server interactions where only one side talks at a time while the other side waits.  For ASCII/text based protocols, it is common to use a control-character delimiter like NL/EOL or NUL or CTX to mark the end of messages.  Binary protocols more commonly use an embedded length field -- the receiver first reads the length and then reads the full amount of (expected) data.

For asynchronous, you use non-blocking mode.  It IS possible to use non-blocking mode with stdio streams, it just requires some care.  out-of-data conditions show up to stdio like error conditions, so you need to use `ferror` and `clearerr` on the `FILE *` as appropriate.

It's possible for both to be used -- for example in client-server interactions, the clients may use synchronous (they send a request and wait for a reply) while the server uses asynchronous (to be be robust in the presence of misbehaving clients).

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment below, in this case there *is* actually some size information embedded in the binary data, just not in any convenient way. To know the size of the structure I would have to process it byte by byte to decode all the recursive subsections that all have their own sizes (and all have different ways of storing the sizes, and for some godforsaken reason all the integers are big endian...). I had hoped to avoid that, but I suppose I have no choice but to go back to the drawing board for this one.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` api on Linux or the `ReadFile` Api on windows will immediately return and not wait for the specified number of bytes to fill the buffer (when reading a pipe or socket). Read then reurns the number of bytes read.

This means, when reading from a pipe, you set a buffersize, read as much as returned and the process it. You then read the next bit. The only time you are blocked is if there is no data available at all.

This differs from `fread` which only returns once the desired number of bytes are returned or the stream determines doing so is impossible (like eof).

Comment: A problem with that approach is that in this application there are periods during which there is no data in the stream, but before the end of the data itself. The "server" I'm requesting the data from has better things to do than respond instantly to any request, and it seems like it sometimes only writes part of the buffer at a time.